# how to include class member function inside another class member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to access a class member function inside another class member function, i guess this is what code reuse is all about. Anyways i have a class and a class header file. the class has one member function to calculate the average of a column in a vector. I need to access this average function in another function for instance datastandardization function as below.

class.cpp has two member function as below

```
float Table::datatSandardization(int row, int col){

    float tableValue,avg=0;

    return avg;

}
```

another member function to calculate average:

```
float Table::displayColAverage(int col){
    float sum=0.0,ave;

 for(register unsigned int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {

        sum = sum + vec[i][col];

    }

return ave=sum/vec.size();

}
```

Now i need to include this average function inside standardization function: for example i want to do something like this:

```
float Table::datatSandardization(int row, int col){

        float tableValue,avg=0;

        avg = displayColAverage(int col);
        return avg;

    }
```

Thanks for looking at this problem.

Comment: `avg = displayColAverage(col);` (note no "int").

Comment: 1 whole day of just programming has made me not to look at a simple problems... that was it .. thanks